# Convert Number stored as Text to Number in column

Tags: vba, excel, formatting

I have a column of mixed data in my Excel sheet where the numbers are formatted as "Text".

Some examples:

- 36
- R4
- 56
- AF PL RFD
- 65
- DHU
- 14

I need to convert all the numeric values in the column to the format "Number" so I can further process the data.

The following throws an error 400 without any further explanation:

```
Sheet1.Range("A2","A50000").Select
With Selection
    .NumberFormat = "General"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

I don't how many rows with values my column will contain so I had to make the range fairly big.

Comment: There are several errors in your code. Tip: try recording a macro instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Avoid trying to **Select** both a worksheet and a range in the same statement *(in fact, you can avoid **Select** completely)*:

```
Sub ytrewq()
    With Sheet1.Range("A2", "A50000")
        .NumberFormat = "General"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

seems to work just fine!

Comment: What also works if there are only numbers is to multiply by 1

Comment: @Luuklag  Good comment! and if there are only numbers, the multiply you mentioned can be performed with an extra cell and *PasteSpecialMultiply*

Answer (score 9):

I have noticed many try to answer this problem with some sort of "Number formatting" such as found in the Home Ribbon.  I think that the concern lies in the extraction of data from a source and having the little green arrow in the cell with a "caution" pop-up when hovering over the cell.   This cannot be fixed with number formatting and has most likely been tried by the person asking for assistance.  I was one of them.

```
With ActiveSheet.Select
    Range("A2:A10000").Select
        For Each xCell In Selection
        xCell.Value = CDec(xCell.Value)
    Next xCell
End With
```

Mabbutt, Dan. "Convert Text to Number in Excel." ThoughtCo, Jun. 14, 2018, thoughtco.com/convert-text-to-number-in-excel-3424223.

Comment: After hours you're the first who understood and solved the problem. This should be voted up much more. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
''Convert text to Number with ZERO Digits and Number convert ZERO Digits  

Sub ZERO_DIGIT()
 On Error Resume Next
 Dim rSelection As Range
 Set rSelection = rSelection
 rSelection.Select
 With Selection
  Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
  .Value = .Value
 End With
 rSelection.Select
  Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
 Set rSelection = Nothing
End Sub

''Convert text to Number with TWO Digits and Number convert TWO Digits  

Sub TWO_DIGIT()
 On Error Resume Next
 Dim rSelection As Range
 Set rSelection = rSelection
 rSelection.Select
 With Selection
  Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
  .Value = .Value
 End With
 rSelection.Select
  Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
 Set rSelection = Nothing
End Sub

''Convert text to Number with SIX Digits and Number convert SIX Digits  


Sub SIX_DIGIT()
 On Error Resume Next
 Dim rSelection As Range
 Set rSelection = rSelection
 rSelection.Select
 With Selection
  Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
  .Value = .Value
 End With
 rSelection.Select
  Selection.NumberFormat = "0.000000"
 Set rSelection = Nothing
End Sub
```