# Copy blank/empty cell and pastespecial add to entire column by column header name

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I'm trying write a MACRO to do the following (As a small portion of a large MACRO project):

(Consider that I will have a varying number of COLUMNS and ROWS each time the report is generated, so, the columns needed manipulated will be different each time. This is why I need to use Header names.)

1. Select a BLANK cell within the existing report data
2. COPY the cell
3. SELECT all data, except for header, in COLUMN where header name = "PROC#/REV CODE"
4. PASTE SPECIAL ADD (this step is to get two separate sets of data into the same (EQUAL IF) comparable data type.
5. REPEAT this entire process for COLUMN where header name = "FEE RATE".

Recorded MACRO looks like this (need to replace "RANGE("K2")" with unknown EMPTY cell location. Need to replace "Range("G2:G4786")" with Column Header NAME):

```
Sub CopySpacePasteAdd()
Range("K2").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("G2").Select
A
Range("G2:G4786").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlAdd, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Thank you SO much for any assistance!

Comment: [Okay](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Have you tried the macro recorder? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried the MACRO recorder. I'm very new to writing the MACROs, so, I'm having trouble putting together the recorded MACRO into the more broad format of "Header Names" instead of selected ranges being under column letters. AND how to auto select the blank cell without knowing the cell name.

Comment: @LittleZenGirl Please always put code into your original question and format it nicely (indent at least 4 spaces). In VBA every line break matters and code in comments is not readable. So please [edit] your question to add the code. • Also a screenshot of your sheet might help to understand your issue better.

Comment: Are you trying to clear all the cells below the columns with headers "PROC#/REV CODE" and  "FEE RATE"?

Comment: GMalc-I'm not trying to CLEAR the cells, I'm trying to SELECT the cells below the columns with heaters "PROC#/REVCODE" and "FEE RATE". Once selected, I'm going to paste/add. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you want to "Select a BLANK cell" and paste it to the range, in my definition that is clearing all the cells below the header. If that is not what you are wanting to do, then you need to edit your question to be clearer.

Comment: GMalc-Thank you so much for trying to assist. Please note number 4 in my question. I want to PASTE SPECIAL ADD. This will not clear the cells-it simply converts the existing data from "Number stored as Text" into number.

Comment: Please take a look at [This SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50569597/excel-vba-convert-number-stored-as-text-to-number-in-column) concerning changing numbers stored as text to number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit; This code is not that pretty, but it will convert text into numbers for the range below the specific headers.

```
Dim lRow As Long

lRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To Columns.Count
    If Cells(1, i) = "PROC#/REV CODE" Then
            With Cells(1, i).Offset(1).Resize(lRow)
                .NumberFormat = "General"
                .Value = .Value
            End With

    ElseIf Cells(1, i) = "FEE RATE" Then
            With Cells(1, i).Offset(1).Resize(lRow)
                .NumberFormat = "General"
                .Value = .Value
            End With

    Exit For

    End If
Next
```

Comment: Gmalc-this last code works GREAT! Thank you SO much!

Comment: Is there any way to select the actual "used range" of the column data, instead of the "Resize(4786)"? My data will sometimes be 2 rows, sometimes more than 10,000 rows.

Comment: Yes, the range can be modified using the last row.

Comment: GMalc-now it is doing exactly what I needed. Thank you SO much!!

Comment: I'm glad i could help.